# WoW macro - how to check where you are?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

You can create a macro to chosese between smimming and flying mounts:

```
/use [flyable] FlyMount
/use [swimming] SwimMount
/dismount [mounted]
```

But some mounts are allowed only in specific area. For example, Vashj'ir. If I'm out of Vashj'ir, then even if I'm swimming I want to mount a FlyMount, since it has some use (I can fly out of water). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you don't mind an addon, I use this: http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/gogomount You can set preferences of mounts, it can also use non-flying mounts only in no-fly-zones, you can set a preferred mount per zone etc etc. You can also define hotkeys for (un-)mounting and a seperate one for flying, non-flying and multi-person mounts.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness, yeah, it works for my specific problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably add a modifier to that macro:

```
/use [flyable] Invincible
/use [swimming][mod:alt] Sea turtle; Invincible
/dismount
```

This should mount sea turtle with no mod pressed while swimming and with alt pressed while swimming should mount Invincible. I am at work so I cannot test if it works but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: +1, but this is not what I wanted. I wanted to make my life easier:) Similarly to your solution I can put 2 different mounts to 2 different keys, it is simpler.

Comment: That does make your life easier, since you can select a flying mount *any time you are swimming*. Real lifesaver when doing a corpse out to the edge of the map in Fatigued country.